# My generic superclass method returns a List of subclass elements how do I Override this method in decendent class to return a List of the subclass

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic superclass  called widgets that is bound to `<T extends widgets<?>>`. The class has a method that returns a List of a specific SubClass when called by an instance of the subclass.  I can get this to compile without warning for direct subclasses. But when I extend the subclass I can't get it to compile.   I am trying to avoid casting in the classes that use the Widget subtypes and warnings.

I have not written generic classes before so I am not sure of the implementation.  I have provided a code code snippet to show what my code structure below.

````
//parent class
package snippets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Widget<T extends Widget<?>> {
      public List<T> buildWidgets() {
            List<T> widgets = new ArrayList<T>();

            for (int index = 0; index < 10; ++index) {
                try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    T widget = (T) this.getClass()
                                        .newInstance();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return widgets;
        }
}


```
//Direct subclass
package snippets;

public class Button extends Widget<Button> {

}

```
//Class that extends the subclass
package snippets;

public class MobileButton extends Button {

}

```
//This class implements the above
package snippets;

import java.util.List;

public class WidgetImplementer {

    public WidgetImplementer() {
        Button buttonBuilder = new Button();
        MobileButton mButtonBuilder = new MobileButton();

        //This compiles
        List<Button> buttons = buttonBuilder.buildWidgets();

        //This does not: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Button> to List<MobileButton>
        List<MobileButton> mButtons = mButtonBuilder.buildWidgets();

    }
}
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Button` class fixates the generic parameter as `Button`. This means that the contract is now `List<Button> buildWidgets()`.
To make the code work, you would have to define `Button` the same way `Widget` is defined: `Button<T extends Button<?>> extends Widget<T>`. And then `MobileButton<T extends MobileButton<?>> extends Button<T>`. You could spare yourself the generic definition of MobileButton, but then you would be stuck there if you ever want to extend it.

Comment: Thanks, This Fixed the compile error.  But I still get a raw Type warning in WidgetImplementer unless I declare the Button as Button<Button<?>>.   Is there a way to code it without specifying the type in the  WidgetImplementer ?

Comment: The rawType warning is, because Button is now a generic type. Simply writing `Button`, you use it a raw type. In your case, you actually want `Button<Button>`, which still might give you a rawType warning. If it does, your way of writing it is the only correct way.

Comment: Btw: If it works, please accept the answer as correct ;)